# Why does my Tic-Tac_Toe computer Ai makes another move when I refresh the browser?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am working on my TicTacToe Game.This is being deployed to Heroku, I've fixed an error where when one person was playing the game and another started to play it from another computer it would update on the seconds players screen what the first player was doing. Then I realized that when I hit refresh on the browser the AI makes another move and will again and again if you continue to refresh the browser. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
post '/game' do

session[:choice] = params[:choice].to_i
choice = params[:choice].to_i
player_marker = players.current_player()

if play_board.square_available?(choice - 1) == true
    play_board.board[choice - 1] = player_marker
    redirect to('/status')
else
    erb :squares, :locals => {:p1 => players.player1, 
                              :p2 => players.player2, 
                              :invaild => "Hey #{players.current} #{choice} is already taken", 
                              :message2 => "Please choose again.", 
                              :current => players.current, 
                              :board => play_board.board, 
                              :type => players.type}
  end   
end

get '/computerai' do
    player_marker = players.current_player()

    move = ai.computer_move()

play_board.board[move] = player_marker
redirect to('/status')
 end

get '/status' do
if play_board.winner?(players.current_player) == true
    redirect to('/win')
elsif play_board.board_full?() == true
    redirect to('/tie')
end

players.current = players.change()
redirect to('/computerai') if players.type == "1" && players.current == 2
erb :squares, :locals => {:p1 => players.player1, 
                          :p2 => players.player2, 
                          :invaild => "", 
                          :message2 => "", 
                          :current => players.current, 
                          :board => play_board.board, 
                          :type => players.type}    
end
```

This is the link to the Github page where my source code is if you need more of the code. https://github.com/josephmckenzie/Tic_tac_toe_online .

```
Called from: C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `new
WARN: tilt autoloading 'tilt/erb' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'tilt/erb' suggested
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:04 -0500] "GET /tictactoe HTTP/1.1" 200 1544 0.3104
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:07 -0500] "POST /tictactoe HTTP/1.1" 200 891 0.0165
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:10 -0500] "POST /marker HTTP/1.1" 200 1521 0.0085
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:11 -0500] "POST /squares HTTP/1.1" 200 944 0.0130
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:14 -0500] "POST /game HTTP/1.1" 303 - 0.0030
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:15 -0500] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0122
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:15 -0500] "GET /computerai HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0104
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:15 -0500] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 200 914 0.0135
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:17 -0500] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0025
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:18 -0500] "GET /computerai HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0131
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:18 -0500] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 200 914 0.0110
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:18 -0500] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0030
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:18 -0500] "GET /mm.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0035
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:00:38:18 -0500] "GET /TicTacToePowerPoint1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0025
```

Comment: So looking at it now I see the first GET /computerai then it checks to see if there is a win or lose. When i refresh/reload the page it checks the status for win,lose or tie and if that condition is not met AI plays . My issue is probably in the status like Mitch said below. So  I have to figure out a way to have it do nothing if the page is refreshed by the player for some reason. hmmm Back to Google.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my refresh issue :) What I did was take out the human move logic and put it it in to it's own /get . So now I can hit refresh on my browser and the ai wont make a another move. I asked my teacher and he basically told me to follow the logic and separate out part of the get/status as well as some other stuff.

```
get '/status' do
if play_board.winner?(players.current_player) == true
    redirect to('/win')
elsif play_board.board_full?() == true
    redirect to('/tie')
end

players.current = players.change()
if players.type == "1" && players.current == 2
 redirect to('/computerai') 
 else
    redirect to('/humanmove')
  end
end



 get '/humanmove' do

players.type == "1" && players.current == 1
    erb :squares, :locals => {:p1 => players.player1, 
                          :p2 => players.player2, 
                          :invaild => "", 
                          :message2 => "", 
                          :current => players.current, 
                          :board => play_board.board, 
                          :type => players.type}    
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

this does not look right:

```
redirect to('/computerai') if players.type == "1" && players.current == 2
erb :squares, :locals => {:p1 => players.player1,
```

unless I am mistaken about how redirect works, you will continue on and still generate the erb response.

I think you want this

```
if players.type == "1" && players.current == 2
  redirect ...
else
  erb ...
end
```

If this doesn't fix it, then please post what request is being made when you refresh the browser... I assume its /status , but I'm not sure...

Comment: I tried what you said it still does it. I added what I think you want to my code up top. Thanks for any help

Comment: why there are two `if` ?

Comment: Joseph if you can store the web based version of the app to github, we can have a look.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn I have the version in my Github that I have on Heroku. My sinatra / ruby app is there.